# How to detect and selecting user local country?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I'm using that library: https://github.com/AlmogBaku/IntlPhoneInput to get user phone number.

I want to detect and select automatically the local country of the user.

Reading that: https://github.com/AlmogBaku/IntlPhoneInput#public-methods, 
I added that: `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` in my AndroidManifest.xml but can't detect and select automatically the local country of the user.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using API-level 23+, then `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` in manifest won't be sufficient and you need to request it programmatically, and to do so

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_READ_STATE = 21;
    private IntlPhoneInput mPhoneInputView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We do not have this permission. Let's ask the user by showingg a dialog
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_READ_STATE);
        }

        mPhoneInputView = findViewById(R.id.my_phone_input);

    }

    // Called when the user decides the dialog permission
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_READ_STATE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission granted!
                mPhoneInputView.setDefault();

            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm android programing learner. Is there any way to always "allow my app to make and manage phone calls" when dialog is shown ?

Comment: @ankalagba you can only manage phone calls after the user grants you this permission, otherwise you can't, also there are other permissions that you may consider for other phone purposes like CALL_PHONE, ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, MODIFY_PHONE_STATE, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS.., some require just manifest declaration, and others requires both manifest and java permissions .. BTW we all are learners :)

Comment: Thanks for your very great answer.

Comment: Sorry to make you back here. Is there any way to remove the placeholder ?

Comment: hi @ankalagba .. any time .. do you mean the `mPhoneInputView` widget?

Comment: I don't know what is "mPhoneInputView" and google a little about it but can't see nothing. Do that library give a possibility to remove or disable the "Automatically set the input placeholder to an example number for the selected country" ?

Comment: @ankalagba .. sorry, it's the name of the widget in my provided code, I mean that you need to know the country from the code without providing this kind of view?

Comment: Yes I want to select the country but remove the placeholder because it not correcte. It does not give the true sample placeholder.

Comment: @ankalagba you  canremove the view from layout, and just create it in your activity to get the country with: `IntlPhoneInput myView = new IntlPhoneInput(this);
myView.getSelectedCountry().getName();`

Comment: "you can remove the view from layout" ? I'm not sure to understand you. I tried that in my activity: IntlPhoneInput myView = new IntlPhoneInput(this);
                myView.getSelectedCountry().getName();
                mPhoneInputView.setDefault(); but nothing changed.

Comment: sorry, I can't get what you want to achieve .. can you illustrate more